# Multi Dropdown parameters and their available values in SSRS reporting

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am looking for help in SSRS reporting. Consider this scenario -- First dropdown has Asia, Europe. if Asia is selected - second dropdown should show China, India, Japan. If Europe is selected, second dropdown should show Italy and Spain.

So the question: In the second dropdown's Available values:

1st available value and Label is like

```
=IIF(Parameters!Continent.Value = "Asia", "China", "Italy")
```

2nd available value and label is like

```
  =IIF(Parameters!Continent.Value = "Asia", "India", "Spain")
```

3rd available value and label is like

```
=IIF(Parameters!Continent.Value = "Asia", "Japan", "*******")
```

What I am looking for is to not show the the third value when Europe is selected. How can I set it to be not visible if Europe is selected?

I hope this scenario makes sense. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Have you considered using datasets for the parameter values? You can make the available values come from a dataset. You can then make one parameter depend on the output from a previous one.

Comment: Ok. Good idea! But how can I get a provide names of the continents and countries to datasets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want **NOTHING**.

```
=IIF(Parameters!Continent.Value = "Asia", "Japan", NOTHING)
```

**Nothing** is how to use a blank (NULL) value in SSRS.

In theory, you should have 2 tables and use parameters. 
A table for your continents with **Continent** and **ContinentID**
Another for your countries with a Continent ID field that relate to the Continent in the above table.

Then you have the continent selection based on your first table:
Select * from Continent

And your country selection based on your first parameter:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Country 
WHERE ContinentID = @Continent
```

This way, only countries that are on the selected continent show up in the country selection.

Comment: I do not have any tables. So i had to use IIF statement and hard code values and Labels. I didn't know there was something called "Nothing". I really appreciate the help. Thanks a lot. :-)

Comment: That's what I figured but thought I would explain what Martin was saying in case you needed to do something like it for something else in the future.